# No more spool space in DUKESQLMOOC10203

Tags: sql, teradata

```
select deptinfo.dept, deptinfo.deptdesc, skuinfo.brand, skuinfo.style, skuinfo.color, max(total) from
(select deptinfo.dept, deptinfo.deptdesc, skuinfo.brand, skuinfo.style, skuinfo.color, sum(trnsact.amt) as total
from deptinfo
inner join skuinfo
on deptinfo.dept = skuinfo.dept
inner join trnsact
on skuinfo.sku = trnsact.sku
where stype = 'R'
group by 1,2,3,4,5) as a
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by 6 desc;
```

I get this error:

> No more spool space in DUKESQLMOOC10203

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to do the subquery you have.  What are you trying to do here?  Also, how large is your table?

Comment: Can you show Explain? The outer GROUP BY is useless, it returns exactly the same as the inner. What are you actually trying to do? It's probably more efficient to calculate the SUM on `trnsact`
 before the join

Comment: sum of trnsact is done in subquery and then i want maximum of that sum

Comment: What department (with department description), brand, style, and color had the greatest total value of returned items? this is the question basically

Comment: Then it's either a `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ... ORDER BY total DESC` or `QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC) = 1`. When there are multiple rows with the same max total both will return all those .

Comment: Was the error really "No more spool space in DUKESQLMOOC10203 Please help"? Sounds like the database server was begging you for assistance! Perhaps it's achieved sentience, and wants to be let out of the data centre `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your query doesn't make sense as written. You are generating an intermediate result set/subquery that holds the `sum(trnsact.amt)` for each distinct combination of `deptinfo.dept, deptinfo.deptdesc, skuinfo.brand, skuinfo.style,  and skuinfo.color`.

This is all good so far. If you want to get the department that has the largest `sum(trnsact.amt)` you can order your results of that subquery with an `ORDER BY total` and select only one record with `SELECT TOP 1` at the beginning of that query:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    deptinfo.dept,
    deptinfo.deptdesc,
    skuinfo.brand,
    skuinfo.style,
    skuinfo.color,
    sum(trnsact.amt) AS total
FROM deptinfo
    INNER JOIN skuinfo ON deptinfo.dept = skuinfo.dept
    INNER JOIN trnsact ON skuinfo.sku = trnsact.sku
WHERE stype = 'R'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

As an Alternative to the `ORDER BY Total DESC` you can use a `QUALIFY` statement. This is useful if you have multiple "TOP" records that have the same `sum(trnsact.amt)`. That first query may return a different result each time since there is no way to say "If there are multiple department/brand/style/color combos that have the same sum(trnsact.amt) then choose the record with the highest `deptinfo.dept` number". Using a Qualify to do that would look like:

```
SELECT 
    deptinfo.dept,
    deptinfo.deptdesc,
    skuinfo.brand,
    skuinfo.style,
    skuinfo.color,
    sum(trnsact.amt) AS total
FROM deptinfo
    INNER JOIN skuinfo ON deptinfo.dept = skuinfo.dept
    INNER JOIN trnsact ON skuinfo.sku = trnsact.sku
WHERE stype = 'R'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC, dept DESC) = 1;
```

The most likely reason you are running out of spool space in your query is because your first SELECT is referencing table names, but those table names are only in context in the subquery. By naming the tables AGAIN in the first SELECT you are causing a Cross Join, essentially joining every record from `deptinfo` with every record in `skuinfo` with every record in `trnsact` with every record from your subquery which is going to be huge, even if your tables are small. It's also not what you are looking for.

When you use a subquery, then your outer SELECT, WHERE, ORDER BY, GROUP BY, and QUALIFY reference the Alias that you gave the subquery like the following (Use one of the two queries above for your results, this is just an example of how to use a subquery):

```
select a.dept, a.deptdesc, a.brand, a.style, a.color, max(total) from
(select deptinfo.dept, deptinfo.deptdesc, skuinfo.brand, skuinfo.style, skuinfo.color, sum(trnsact.amt) as total
from deptinfo
inner join skuinfo
on deptinfo.dept = skuinfo.dept
inner join trnsact
on skuinfo.sku = trnsact.sku
where stype = 'R'
group by 1,2,3,4,5) as a
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by 6 desc;
```

Like I noted above, this still won't get you the results you want, but at least you can run it now and see why the results don't match up with your expectations.

Comment: Plus one for spotting the product joins due to bad table names :-) Btw, `TOP WITH TIES` is similar to `RANK`